# Can JavaScript and PHP prove an online card game?

Tags: php, javascript, performance

I want to ask, is possible to create on-line card game, only with using JavaScript, PHP and AJAX (no Flash)?

The game should work like - every player will have a deck with X cards (sixty for instance) to play, each with original abilities. The game must assess every action in game (for instance - a card has ability to draw another card, the game must draw a card, and so) and system must control the action possibility. All that stuff would control PHP. Javascript would only send questions accros the AJAX and would only receive simple commands (like draw a card, move that card from hand to play).

Another thing is the game synchronize (using AJAX again), like player must always see, what is his opponent doing (about one request for second, i gues). Can JavaScript hold all these stuffs? Will the AJAX request be fast enough? Can PHP assess the game fast enough (With a good-writed core application)?

Thank you

PS: I do not insist on supporting older browsers (like IE7,8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**. It is possible.

Comment: OK, thank you :) That's what I wanted to know